# Sitecore solr list of double/float field

Tags: solr, content-search

It`s weird but I did not find any *fieldtype* for storage list of doubles/floats both in **Sitecore** and in **Solr** *(I need this field just for storing, not for querieng)*.

Just need to store **List< double>** result of *ComputedField* in **Solr**.

I hope that many of you faced/solved this lack. Could you help me?

*Sitecore 9.3 and Solr 8.8.1 if it is important.*

Comment: what's wrong with the Number field type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. Sitecore and Solr don't have a field type to map a collection or an array of doubles or floats.

These are the available `multiValued` field types automatically matched by Sitecore:

```
<typeMatch typeName="guidCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]"     fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="textCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_txm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="stringCollection"   type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="intCollection"      type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"    fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="stringArray"        type="System.String[]"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="intArray"           type="System.Int32[]"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="datetimeArray"      type="System.DateTime[]"                                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
<typeMatch typeName="datetimeCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```

You will need to implement the following steps to define a new custom `multiValued` field type for a double collection and apply it to your computed field:

1. You need to define a new custom dynamicField in your index `managed-schema.xml` file:

```
<dynamicField name="*_tdm" type="pdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

2. Then you will need to patch the `typeMatches` defined in the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` to add a new custom typeMatch:

```
<typeMatch typeName="doubleCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```

3. And finally you will need to use this new type in the definition of your computed field in the `returnType` property, in both following sections of your index configuration. For example:

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
  <field fieldName="myDoubleCollectionField" returnType="doubleCollection">MyAssembly.CustomComputedField,MyAssembly</field>
</fields>
```

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
  <field fieldName="myDoubleCollectionField" returnType="doubleCollection" />
</fieldNames>
```

Comment: Modifying the managed schema file is dangerous as it would get overwritten if the user populated the managed schema through the Sitecore Control Panel. Instead, you can add a processor to the contentSearch.PopulateSolrSchema pipeline that adds in the dynamic field, and then repopulate the managed schema. Here's one example of doing that. https://sitecoreblog.marklowe.ch/2018/10/customize-solr-managed-schema/

Comment: Thank you Matthew for your addition! I totally agree and thank you for sharing it.